# bootbox.alert not working from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I am importing data to DB from excel using bootstrap file uploader. After data import I need to show a message to user. So I have  below code

```
        string strScript = "bootbox.alert('" + Resources.Resource.Success_SaveUserInfo + "');";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UserSave", strScript, true);
```

But it is not working. Page get freeze instead of alert. But if I use below code it work.

```
  string strScript = "alert('" + Resources.Resource.Success_SaveUserInfo + "');";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UserSave", strScript, true);
```

I have already added **bootbox.min.js**. So it is not issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
string strScript = "<script type = 'text/javascript'>bootbox.alert('" + Resources.Resource.Success_SaveUserInfo + "');</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UserSave", strScript, true);
```

**OR**

Call javascript function it's highly recommended and reusable as well

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UserSave", CustomalertFunction('" + Resources.Resource.Success_SaveUserInfo + "'), true);
```

and write a javascript function

```
function CustomalertFunction(message)
{
  bootbox.alert(message);
}
```

Comment: already tried not working above code. But strange is if I modify  bootbox.alert(message); to simple alert is work

Comment: Ohkk now what you do is just add `bootbox.alert()` on `document.ready` and check is it working if no than check you have added scripts related to bootbox it seems like script is missing in your page let me know if it's working

Comment: Ohh i know you have mentioned that you have already added `bootbox.min.js` please make sure you have added related css for that as well `bootbox.css` and jquery min js also there in the page at the **top of all js**